# What's a compact scientific answer to question "(Why there is) / (what is before) the Big Bang?"

Tags: cosmology, big-bang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did spacetime start with the Big bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5150/did-spacetime-start-with-the-big-bang)
>   [on causality and The Big Bang Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7838/on-causality-and-the-big-bang-theory)
>   [Before the Big Bang](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/before-the-big-bang)

What's a compact scientific answer to question "(Why there is) / (what is before) the Big Bang?"  Some fellow physics / science students ask question "what is before the Big Bang?" or alternatively "Why there is a Big Bang" (assuming the time dimension and hence 'before' is ill-defined at the event of Big Bang).  We couldn't get any qualitative answer we universally agree on.  Is there some compact way to answer this?

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41501/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/

Comment: I think this question has been extensively covered already.  If you click on the big-bang tag, and scroll through there you'll find lots of information