# Big Bang, What is wrong with such thinking?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, space-expansion, antimatter

Also if I think the Expanding of Universe like this:

At the Start : The Amount of Matter and Anti-Matter is equal and they annihilate and all we had is Large Amount of energy.

But some 'X' Thing, disturbed this symmetry. So matter start to be in excess so we have some part of universe.

The Excess rate of creation of matter continued for many year as resulted in our day universe. And still the rate of Creation of Matter is greater than its anti-matter pair.
Thus the Universe is Expanding.

Does this thinking seem correct? If not what is wrong?

Comment: The first and last sentences of this question are one question, which is a duplicate. The material in between is a whole different question, and displays a bunch of strange misconceptions about the Big Bang.

Comment: possible duplicate of [At what speed does our universe expand?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13388/)

Comment: Ok , Edited. @BenCrowell , What are the misconceptions ?

Comment: matter and antimatter are concepts coming from the microcosm of particle physics, strong, weak and electromagnetic forces. The Big Bang comes from  the General Relativity equations for specific boundary values modeling  observational facts  , i.e. gravity alone http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang . Examining the possible behavior of matter as composed by the standard model particles follows this model, and examines what happens to the elementary particles under the extreme conditions of the big bang. It is gravity that reigns at the beginning of the universe to start with.

Answer (score 1):

> At the Start : The Amount of Matter and Anti-Matter is equal and they annihilate and all we had is Large Amount of energy .

There wasn't a time when we had matter and antimatter, followed by a time when they annihilated one another, followed by a time when there was pure energy. Rates of processes like this were locally in thermal equilibrium.

> But some 'X' Thing , disturbed this symmetry .. so matter start to be in excess so we have some part of universe .

OK, this X would be something that satisfied the [Sakharov conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakharov_conditions#Sakharov_conditions).

> The Excess rate of creation of matter continued for many year as resulted in our day universe

No, the Sakharov conditions would only have been satisfied for a very short time. I don't think we have an accurate estimate of the time, but it would definitely be less than 1 minute.

> And still the rate of Creation of Matter is greater than its anti-matter pair . Thus the Universe is Expanding .

Expansion of the universe has nothing to do with creation of matter.

Comment: Thnaks , but if not excess of matter made Universe Expand , then what did ? ..
Also if , Excess of matter cant expand universe .. so it must increase the density of it ... Is the rate of matter creation possibly be greater than c ?

Comment: @user2876151: *but if not excess of matter made Universe Expand , then what did ?* See this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7838/on-causality-and-the-big-bang-theory . I don't understand why you think there is a link between creation of matter and cosmological expansion. *Also if , Excess of matter cant expand universe .. so it must increase the density of it* Expansion of the universe causes a decrease in the density of matter, not an increase. *Is the rate of matter creation possibly be greater than c ?* There is no matter creation.

Answer (score 0):

The astrophysical observations of the motions galaxies, clusters of galaxies  and of the microwave cosmic radiation led to the hypothesis that the Universe started at some point and has been expanding since then. This hypothesis has not been falsified by new data and has been going with the name [Big Bang theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) since the 1920s, from the kinematic analogy with an explosion.

These observations depend entirely on gravity, not elementary particles and their annihilation, and gravitation is described at large distances by General Relativity with Newtonian mechanics being the limiting case as distances get small. In particular the Big Bang  has been [modeled mathematically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) with in the framework of  General Relativity .

In [special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) which is necessary to describe the behavior of elementary particles, it is energy that can be manifested as  mass or radiation or kinetic energy. Thus given an amount energy there can be creation and annihilation of particles. This is in the micro domain. In the Big Bang model the expansion starts because the spacetime is changing, expanding.

In the first moments of the Big Bang the energy cannot be described by particles we  know,only as the expansion cools the universe we can get the quark gluon plasma, which currently is being studied at the LHC. **Thus particle creation is an effect of the expansion, not the cause of the expansion** .

As the expansion continues the universe cools enough for the plasma to coagulate into protons and neutrons  and electrons and their antiparticles. It is still a matter of research why there are particles only in our known universe.

These matters are described in the wiki article on the big bang, but to really understand them time should be spent in learning the mathematics necessary to understand the theories behind the model