# Does the big bang violate the conservation of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, time, energy-conservation, big-bang

It is a fact that a thing is existing now because it had already been created. So why don't we take this to account to redefine law of conservation of energy.

Comment: Please don't shout. I've already edited one of your posts. Haven't you learned from that?

Comment: Yes. As @Jan Dvorak said, don't use all capitals.

Comment: Possibility 1: this is a genuine question asked in good faith, if in poor style. In that case the search bar and google are your friends. This question has been asked and answered many times already. Possibility 2: all those cosmologists with physics Ph.D's and hundreds of years of experience between them never thought of asking a high school level question in relation to their field. Possibility 3: you're trolling, don't know what you're talking about and don't actually care about the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/2451 Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/2451

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/

Answer (score 1):

The law of conservation of energy says that the total energy of  an isolated system does not depend on time.

Fortunately,   the big bang was also the beginning of time.