# What existed before Big Bang?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, big-bang

This is one of the most famous and trending question in today's world.
Well , before you answer this question I want to say that before answering this question you must know about the Big Bang Theory & Big Bang Theory .

{ My motive to ask this question is that think deeply to answer this question and not by guesses .}

Comment: You can find the answer to this question by going to the North Pole and then walking 100m due north

Comment: Theres no sense to ask what was before the Big Bang. It does not make sense to talk about it. Its also not a question of physics but maybe metaphysics

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. The other asked specifically about the start of spacetime, this question is more generally about "before" the big bang, which raises the issue of temporal vs causal meanings of "before".

Answer (score -2):

So , according to Sir Stephen William Hawking , NOTHING existed before Big Bang , as many of you may have seen in the interview of Sir Stephen Hawking (if not I had put a link below , just check it) .
But if we think deeply for a while, if our universe has started witha Singularity (Big Bang),according to Big Bang Theory , and is going to end at a Singularity (Big Crunch) , according to Big Crunch Theory , so it can also happen that another universe had existed before the Big Bang which had collapsed into a singularity and then exploded and then everything came into existence, which WE now call as Big Bang .

It appears like a cycle in which a universe exploded from a singularity and then it will collapse into a singularity and singularity will again explode and another universe will come into existence .

Comment: There is a reason this stuff is called "theoretical" physics.

Comment: The [current model of cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model) does not include any Big Crunch. It predicts that the universe will continue to expand forever, faster and faster.