# Can there be a start of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, conservation-laws, universe, big-bang

I remembered learning about the essential law of conservation of mass, stating that no mass/matter can be made or destroyed.

That got me thinking, if no matter can be made or destroyed, then there can't be a start of the universe right? Because, the Solar System was formed by the Big Bang, the Big Bang was mainly formed of the Hydrogen and Helium, which may have been given out by the explosion of a star, and you can keep on going back and back. But, even if you reach a point at which you might feel that it's the start of the universe, it can't be! That also would be created by something else! Then there can't possibly be a start of the universe right?

Am I thinking right?

Comment: Conservation of mass/energy applies to this universe. Outside/before/whatever this universe is more philosophy than physics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Ishaan Manish:  There are flaws in the formulation of the earlier question to which you've been referred, which imply a preference for a created universe, dual universe, or multiverse that would necessarily be incomplete, as the creation of its Creator or creators would not be explained.  This is not necessarily a philosophical issue, if experiment or observation have supported any of the answers to it.

Comment: The possibility of a creator or (or creators) existing outside of any of the universe or universes which that entity (or entities) had created would simply be a variation on the dual universe or multiverse themes already modeled in contemporary physics.