# Theoretical: what is the meaning of nothing?

Tags: cosmology, time, big-bang

Before the big bang, there was a point surrounded by nothing (no space or anything). Then the big bang happened and the universe expanded. so beyond the universe's limits, there is nothing? I don't understand this, can someone help me? I'm not a physicist I just wonder. and also the expanding rate of the universe affects the speed of time or not?

Comment: Physics is an experimental science. How would you measure the speed of time?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Physics is also a theoretical science.  How would you *define* the speed of time?

Comment: *beyond the universe's limits* In the current cosmological model, the universe has no boundaries/edges/limits.