# Is time infinite?

Tags: time, universe

If time has a beginning, must it not exist for some amount of "time"? If not, it exists from the point when existence started and if there was ABSOLUTELY no existence there may not exist something that created it, so it makes it obvious that something must exist for infinite amount of time in our universe. Am I wrong?

EDIT:

OK, i will tell you what this question related to in my opinion.

Let's imagine, that the upper theory is right (can exist with all physical issues), so leads to some elements or materials to exist with it, because time cannot exist by its own (if there is nothing, that can change its state the time cant change as well and cant start to create something), so there must be some dimension and time that exist for infinity, and if not there is now way it can physically appear. Am i right? this question relates to physics (for example: if there was no dimension and no time, there was no time and place for big bang, or other thing that changed it to its currently state).

P.S.
I know that this is kind of a discussion, but just tell me, are there arguments that make this kind of thing wrong or this is true?

EDIT:
Is this purely philosophical questions? I don't think so, but i may be wrong.

Comment: Philosophical..

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2355/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't know if you are right or wrong, I only know that physics does not take any philosophical approach to time, boringly perhaps, it just uses a clock.

Comment: This is a better fit for http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/, where there are several related discussions such as http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2351 and http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/10397

Comment: Yes, its kind of philosophical question, but i want to know how physics look at this thing. Is this question is fully related to Philosophy?

Comment: This is somewhere between metaphysics and ontology, both of which are considered philosophy rather than physics in this day and age. Note too that there are some wild leaps in your logic from premises to conclusions. Ideally studying philosophy (as opposed to just thinking about it on your own) would help to train your thinking to be more careful.